# Push Values to Multi Select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need to push values which i am getting from database to multi select.Below code will push data to text area based on onchange in select.I need to change text area to multi select.How to achieve this? Calling below method like

HTML

```
<select id="select-execution-group-update" class="form-control" onchange="getParamListForCustomGroupUpdate()">
```

//JS file

```
    function getParamListForCustomGroupUpdate() {

var selected_execution_group = document.getElementById("select-execution-group-update").value;

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "getObjectList",
    data: {
        execution_group_name: selected_execution_group
    },
    success: function (result) {
        result = result.replace(/\\/g, "");
        document.getElementById("object_custom_name").value = result;
    }

}

);
```

}

Comment: What is in the ajax result? Is it an array? Can you show the result?

Comment: Yes. ,Device-1,Device -2, Device-3

Comment: @Raja1983 can you please send me sample response so that I can give you an accurate answer.

Comment: yes.result is ,Device.10001.Enable\
,Device.WiFi.AccessPoint.101\
,Device.WiFi.AccessPoint.101.Security\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply have to replace text area with the multi-select and append the value in that multi-select.

```
<select id="select-execution-group-update" class="form-control" onchange="getParamListForCustomGroupUpdate()">
<select id='multi-select' ...>

//JS file

    function getParamListForCustomGroupUpdate() {

var selected_execution_group = document.getElementById("select-execution-group-update").value;

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "getObjectList",
    data: {
        execution_group_name: selected_execution_group
    },
    success: function (result) {
        result = result.replace(/\\/g, "").split(',');
        var arrayLength = result.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
            var option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = result[i];
            option.value = result[i];
            var select = document.getElementById("multi-select");
            select.appendChild(option);    
        }
    }
}

);
```

Comment: It is coming as single option.,device1,device 2,device 3.

Comment: @Raja1983 you can try now.

Comment: @Raja1983 and please accept the answer if it works now.

Comment: Thanks.Getting error-Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: I found an issue.It is coming.But coming as single letters

Comment: @Raja1983 can you please share the value of the result variable by printing on console.

Comment: <option value="D">D</option>,<option value="e">e</option>

Comment: i couldn't copy results.Developer tools i  saw above results

Comment: what is returning data of getObjectList action ?@Raja1983

Comment: result is ,Device.10001.Enable\ ,Device.WiFi.AccessPoint.101\ ,Device.WiFi.AccessPoint.101.Security\

Comment: @Raja1983 add this at the end on gsub line .split(',')

Comment: How to clear values in select.Every time i will get new values.If i select Test it will push different value,if i select testing it will push different value.Every time selection i need to clear multi select

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('#multi-select option').forEach(option => option.remove()) add this line before var select = .... @Raja1983

Comment: I have removed.

Answer (score 1):

```
 function getParamListForCustomGroupUpdate() {

var selected_execution_group = document.getElementById("select-execution-group-update").value;

$.ajax({
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    url: "getObjectList",
    data: {
        execution_group_name: selected_execution_group
    },
    success: function (result) {
        // result in array
        result = result.replace(/\\/g, "");
        referenceNode = document.getElementById("object_custom_name");
        //document.getElementById("object_custom_name").value = result;
        var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");

        //Create and append select list
        var selectList = document.createElement("select");
        selectList.id = "mySelect";
        myDiv.appendChild(selectList);

        //Create and append the options
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
           var option = document.createElement("option");
           option.value = result[i];
           option.text = result[i];
           selectList.appendChild(option);
        }
        referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(myDiv, referenceNode.nextSibling);
    }

}
```

Comment: getting array is not defined